# Filter Google Cloud Security Command Center Findings by Folder

Tags: security, google-cloud-platform

I am trying to filter Google Cloud Security Command Center finding notifications by filter using this link.  https://cloud.google.com/security-command-center/docs/how-to-api-filter-notifications

state or parent works fine to filter for.  source_properties is one of the fields.  Within source_properties ResourcePath is one of the fields, but when I submit to create a field I get back ERROR: (gcloud.scc.notifications.create) INVALID_ARGUMENT: Invalid Filter. If specified, filter should be on a field in the request.

Have tried "state = "ACTIVE" AND source_properties.resourcepath.folders = "456353778849""" filters like this.  Anyone had any luck with this and what syntax do you use?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use this format `state="ACTIVE" AND source_properties.resourcepath:"456353778849"`

The colon `:` is a "contain" notation.